# Meteor updating client whenever a server variable changes

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to update a Client template whenever a Server variable changes in a Meteor app?

Based on Meteor docs and searching the web, the only way discussed several times to get the Client side updated whenever Server variable changes is by using a Collection then insert a new document whenever the Server variable change, then through Publish/ Subscribe the client side can get notified, but I was wondering if it there is any other way I can get the Client notified whenever the Server variable changes without the need to use the collections approach. Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you looked into the `Session` variable? They do exactly what you want. Change on either client or server and the change propagates through the app.

Comment: @Louis93, `Session` is only available on the client. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session

Comment: Huh, turns out they made it client only post 1.0. OP, more reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397609/meteor-session-replacement

Comment: Also here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/614

Comment: @MChan, I think doing it through a collection via Pub/Sub might be the only out-of-the-box way. Also consider that there's more to this than "whenever a server variable changes." Many clients are connected to one server (usually). So when something on the server changes, do you want to push it out to all clients? Only one specific client? Some clients, but not all? The pub/sub system allows fine control over this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

even that you have already written about collection to share data between client and server, I suppose, that you do not like the "default" consequence to have a mongodb collection for that.

That is not necessary at all. Lets say, you have a server side state object:

```
ServerStates = {
  version: "1.0",
  date: "2015-07-07"
}
```

This should be send out to all clients (broadcast) who are subscribed

server.js

```
Meteor.publish("server_states", function() {
  // we setup the collection to client just return just on record
  this.insert("server_states", "ServerStates", ServerStates);
  // signal ready
  this.ready();
});
```

On Client you can use now a minimongo collection to get those information

client.js

```
ServerStates = new Meteor.Collection("server_states");

Meteor.subscribe("server_states")
```

If you change a value somewhere on server, you can use my answer from [meteor - get all subscriber session handles for a publisher method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180799/meteor-get-all-subscriber-session-handles-for-a-publisher-method/31221575#31221575) to publish to all active subscribers.

```
// publish updated values to all subscribers
function publish_server_state_to_all() {
  _.each(Meteor.server.stream_server.open_sockets, function(connection) {
    _.each(connection._meteorSession._namedSubs, function(sub) {
      if (sub._name == "server_state") {
        sub.changed("server_state", "ServerState", ServerState);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

So if you change a value from ServerState on server side you can do and inform by

```
ServerState.version = "1.1"

publish_server_state_to_all()
```

Hope that fits your thoughts
Tom

Comment: There might be some interesting infos also for inside this forum entry at: https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-and-the-internet-of-things-iot-whats-best-to-use-collection-meteor-streams-streamy/792/11?u=tomfreudenberg